# How do I create a basic submission form in rails and write to a database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, get

I'm trying to build a micro-app where a user pastes a link, clicks submit, the link is added to the database and is also shown (called from the database) in a list below the submission form.

I've created a Rails app and in the index.html.erb file I have this:

```
<%= form_tag("/search", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Please Paste your Link here") %> <br /> <br />
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

That code has been repurposed from a tutorial site so the /search destination in the first line doesn't point to anywhere real in my app.

I'm trying to simply get this submission to go into my database that I created running `bundle exec rake db:create`

Not sure what to do next to get the link I paste to enter be logged in the database.

Comment: And what else have you done? Have you created a model or controller? Have you read the beginning Rails Guides, available free on rubyonrails.org? The very first Rails Guide, Getting Started With Rails, will get you 95% of the way there: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Agreed with jordan, have a look at the guides. Essentially what you need is to create a simple Model and Controller to support this.

Comment: "micro-app" sounds to me like Sinatra (http://www.sinatrarb.com/) would be the better framework for this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a little bit of a learning curve that you'll need to achieve before you can complete what you're trying to do. Your application will require a controller, model and some routes at least in order to get that form working correctly.

I'd suggest taking a look at some introduction videos that should be able to cover most/all of what you require.

There are some videos available here for free: http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts
Rails for zombies is also a great way to learn rails interactively http://railsforzombies.org/

If you're not a video person then there are plenty of books available which cover all the info you need.

Hope this helps.